# FileSystemWatcher for ListBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `listBox1` and `listBox2` which are loaded with some files from a directory. Initially when I load the form I disabled buttons for the `listBox1` and `listBox2`.

When there is no file in the directory I want to disable the button1 for  `listBox1` and button2 `listBox2`.

But I want to enable the `buttons` of the corresponding `listBox1` and `listBox2` if there is a single file in the directory and if there is any change in the files.

How do i perform this using  `FileSystemWatcher` ??? I need some idea to perform this.

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
  DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
  FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
  foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
  {
    lsb.Items.Add(file);
  }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FileInfo file = (FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
  string path = file.FullName;
  DisplayFile(path);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I have initialized a method here, from here how can i proceed???

```
public void filesystemwatcher()
{
  FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  watcher.Path = @"C:\LoadFiles\";                      
}
```

Comment: Did you try to handle the OnChanged or OnCreated event?

Comment: A quick google for "c# use filesystemwatcher" brings this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar: working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a BindingList with the FileSystemWatcher:

```
BindingList<string> _Files = new BindingList<string>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  _Files.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(Files_ListChanged);
  fileSystemWatcher1.Deleted += fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted;
  fileSystemWatcher1.Created += fileSystemWatcher1_Created;
  fileSystemWatcher1.Renamed += fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed;
  fileSystemWatcher1.Path = @"C:\TestLoadFiles\";

  foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(fileSystemWatcher1.Path)) {
    _Files.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
  }
  listBox1.DataSource = _Files;
}

private void Files_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
  button1.Enabled = (_Files.Count > 0);
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e) {
  _Files[_Files.IndexOf(e.OldName)] = e.Name;
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
  _Files.Remove(e.Name);
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
  _Files.Add(e.Name);
}
```

Comment: :Error No overload for 'fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted' matches delegate 'System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler'

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ All I did was place a FileSystemWatcher component on my form, which defaulted to the name `fileSystemWatcher1`, and added the code you see in the post.  The form obviously included a ListBox and a Button.